# Is it possible to lift an object from rest with constant power?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, power, calculus

This is inspired by [the following question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/622185/).

Consider some object which I want to lift **from rest** with a constant power throughout the whole process; the power I apply when lifting the object from rest is the same power I apply to keep lifting it. The force $F$ and the speed $v$ may change, but power may not.

The power is $P=Fv$. If we want constant power, then $dP/dt=0$.

First, differentiate wrt time, $$\dfrac{dP}{dt} = F \dfrac{dv}{dt}+v \dfrac{dF}{dt}.$$

Set equal to zero, this guarantees constant power, which implies:

$$F \dfrac{dv}{dt} = -v\dfrac{dF}{dt}.$$

From there, I use $F=\dfrac{d(mv)}{dt}\implies F = m\dfrac{dv}{dt}$ and get $$\left( \dfrac{dv}{dt} \right)^2 + v\dfrac{dv}{dt} = 0.$$

How may I solve this non-linear ODE?

---

EDIT: Initially, I got to the wrong conclusion that $F(v-v_0) = -v(F-F_0)$ is a solution. That's what the answer by Vilvanesh addresses.

Comment: If power is constant then this must mean that the quantity Fv is constant. What does this tell you about the derivatives above?

Comment: if F increased by a factor of x, then v is multiplied by a factor of 1/x. However, this becomes tricky when the initial speed is 0, which is why I ask the question

Comment: So the F and v are changing, so how can dP/dt=0?

Comment: that is the question. is there a continuous force I can apply such that the power remains constant. the answer is of course trivial for an object that has non zero initial velocity -- the speed and force just stay the same. however I am not sure what to make of this when the object is lifted from rest

Comment: Why did you assume the force is not a function of the velocity?

Comment: Your question seems contradictory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left( \dfrac{dv}{dt} \right)^2 + v\dfrac{dv}{dt} = 0$$
$$\frac{dv}{dt}\times\Big[\frac{dv}{dt}+v\Big]=0$$

When $\displaystyle{\frac{dv}{dt}=0}$, $v$ has to be a constant. But that isn't possible because initially it was at rest but while being lifted, it is not.
$$\frac{dv}{dt}+v=0$$
$$\frac{dv}{v}=-dt$$
$$\int\limits_{v_o}^v\frac{dv}{v}=-\int\limits_0^tdt$$
$$\ln{v}-\ln{v_o}=-t$$
But since $v_o=0$, $\ln{v_o}$ won't be defined.

Hence a solution doesn't exist for the above differential equation.

Comment: so it is therefore impossible to lift an object with constant power. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your discussion is valid till $\displaystyle{F\frac{dv}{dt}=-v\frac{dF}{dt}}$.

I think the only way to reach $F(v-v_o)=v(F-F_o)$, is by assuming $F$ is constant while integrating on the left side and by assuming $v$ as constant while integrating on the right side. This is inconsistent because on the left side $F$ is being treated as a constant and on the right side it is treated as a variable. Same is applicable for $v$.

Comment: Updated my question. I accepted your post since it did answer my initial question, but any advice for my updated post is much appreciated